# Boron nitride polymerization with silicon based molecules

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds, applied-chemistry

Since boron nitride is similar to carbon hexagonal structures and silicon is a main component of inorganic polymers. Is it possible to make it from a polymer under certain conditions, if so what catalysts are needed?